# Paypal Adaptive Pay Error 520003 Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a working version of Paypal adaptive pay on my domain. I copied all of the code exactly and put it on a new domain and I receive the error.  It is the exact same code and it works on one domain but fails on the other.

```
520003 Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
```

Comment: Hi, Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my LAMP server was running PHP 5.2 vs the other one was running 5.3